# Writing a series from 1 ... 8?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to write two expressions.

- For each $t$ outputs `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` for $t=0,1, \ldots, \infty$.
- For each $t$ outputs `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8` for $t=0,1, \ldots, \infty$.

I have thought about
$$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} n \qquad 1 \leq n \leq 8$$
but how do I get $n$ to run from `1 ... 8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first expression try,

$$t\mod8 + 1$$

(In a programming language that would be $(t\%8)+1$)

For the second, try

```
c=t%8 + 1
n = c*(c+1)/2
```

$$c(c+1)/2$$ is a well known formula for the sum of the first c natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

**For the series:**

I am uncertain about what you mean, but...

$$\sum_{n=1}^{8} n = 1 + 2 +3 +4 + 5+ 6+ 7 + 8$$

In a summation, the variable and its starting value goes on the bottom of the sigma, and the ending value goes on top (so here we let *n* go from 1 to 8). What then happens is that we evaluate the inside of the summation for each integer *n* from the starting value to the ending value.

I'm not sure where *t* comes into it, unless you mean that you want the answer to be independent of *t*, in which case we just ignore the *t* completely:

$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{8} n $$

Alternatively, if you mean you want the *t* to be the ending value, then:

$$ f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{t} n $$

**For the sequence:**

There is no special notation for sequences, so to speak. You could write it as:

$$1, 2, 3, ..., 8$$

What is important is that you include the first term, the last term, and enough other terms to make clear what the pattern is. If we omitted the 3 here, for example, one might misconstrue the sequence as increasing powers of 2, and thus be:

$$1, 2, 4, 8$$

which is not what is wanted.